# SomeClass &a = *new SomeClass(...)

Tags: c++, reference

I have come across a construct that I have not seen before and am wondering what the purpose of it is:

```
{
    SomeClass &a = *new SomeClass(...);

    a.someFunc();
}
```

If my understanding is correct, `a` is a reference to `SomeClass`, and is created via `new`. What purpose does this serve? I.e., why couldn't this have been written as `SomeClass a(...)`? Also, does this code leak memory? My guess is that it does, as `new` is called with no matching `delete`.

Comment: That is pure evil. Replace it with `SomeClass a(...);`

Comment: Yes on both your conjectures. As for the purpose of this... I'd guess a newbie c++ developer coming from the world of Java.

Comment: If `someFunc` contains `delete this` then that would be a reason to use this form over `Someclass a(...);`, and it wouldn't leak. Though of course it would make everything even more evil.

Comment: Quote: "Sorry, that should have been SomeClass a(...), not SomeClass &a(...). I've edited the question to reflect that." The edit ?

Comment: @DieterLücking: The edit is in the question itself, not the code segment. That is, if you read the third sentence after the code block, "I.e., why couldn't this have been written as `SomeClass a(...)`?" it previously said `SomeClass &a(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What purpose does this serve?

Rep generation on Stack Overflow. Or perhaps someone deliberately trying to get fired.

> why couldn't this have been written as SomeClass a(...)

It should have been.

> Also, does this code leak memory? My guess is that it does, as `new` is called with no matching `delete`.

Yes, indeed.

Comment: Sorry, that should have been `SomeClass a(...)`, not `SomeClass &a(...)`. I've edited the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

This indicates that `SomeClass` is a weird non-standard object that can only be created on the heap, not on the stack, or statically.  So you should look out for other weird things that `SomeClass` does:

- it may well create a new thread in its constructor that takes over ownership of the object.
- it is likely that some method(s) of the object will implicitly delete it at some point.

That said, this probably indicates that `SomeClass` was badly misdesigned, possibly to try to encapsulate some behavior written in some other programming language.